# What should be sent to astronomy.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, migration

Obviously, there's a lot of overlap between physics and astronomy. It would be good to have some guidelines for what goes where now that the [astronomy beta](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) is live.

Example questions for discussion:

1. [Why do we say that the earth moves around the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10933/why-do-we-say-that-the-earth-moves-around-the-sun)
2. [Questions about the solar system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8502/questions-about-the-solar-system)
3. [The final death of a black hole.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/the-final-death-of-a-black-hole)
4. [What is meant by positive and negative gravity/energy/spactimecurvature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/what-is-meant-by-positive-and-negative-gravity-energy-spactimecurvature)
5. [Would a submarine float in the atmosphere of Jupiter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/would-a-submarine-float-in-the-atmosphere-of-jupiter)
6. [What nonlinear deformations will a fast rotating planet exhibit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/what-nonlinear-deformations-will-a-fast-rotating-planet-exhibit)

I'm leaving out really obviously astronomy questions like [What is 656 Beagle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/what-is-656-beagle). The big question marks are:

- Classical mechanics/dynamics questions that are principally about astronomical objects
- Cosmology
- General Relativity

Where do those go?

Comment: Cosmology definitely goes with GR in Physics. Cosmology is to astronomy as atomic physics is to chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

My usual position is that questions that are well suited to either site stay where the OP puts them. This *does* have the side effect of creating duplicate question on the two sites.

But I will suggest some principles:

- Questions about *particular* astronomical objects (i.e. the X ray source in Cygnus as opposed to a general question about black hole emissions which could go to either site) belong on Astronomy.
- Questions about astronomical observations, instruments (again *"How telescopes work?"* is good on either, *"What are the current limits on angular resolution of ground based optical telescopes"* is astronomy specific) , and data sets belong on Astronomy. Likewise for questions about getting telescope time or other cultural issues (if you are accepting those).
- Questions where the answer is in some sense wrapped up in the politics of the discipline (i.e. *"What qualifies a body as a planet and why are these conditions important enough to justify demoting Pluto?"*) got to Astronomy. {*}

<s>I see that there is a [*"What should we do with questions which are really physics questions"*](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/211) entry on meta.astronomy, and it already hosts some suggests for the kinds of questions that should be moved here.</s> That link pointed at a question on the meta of the first [astronomy.se] which dies in beta. The same numbered meta question on the current [astronomy.se] seems to be about naming the chatroom.

---

{*} Aside: I was lucky enough to talk to Clive Tombaugh a couple of times during the last years of his life. Seemed like a nice guy.

Comment: in addition to this, which I agree with, I want to emphasize that *some cross-site duplication is explicitly OK*. The audiences are generally different and will provide different takes on similar questions. Lots of cross-site duplication would be bad, but some is OK and even healthy: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Are you sure the link in your answer points to the correct question?

Comment: @ChristianRau It does not. That's because it points at a question that used to exist on the meta of the *old* astronomy stack exchange site (that died in beta and was mostly merged with [physics.se]). I guess I'll just scrub that paragraph. Thanks.