# Should users be cross-posting questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Recently we have entertained a new use on Physics.SE (and notably on Astronomy.SE) who has four times posted identical (or nearly so) question to both Physics and Astronomy in short order. (Not that this question is meant to pick on the user in question, just that seeing these posts has brought the situation to the forefront of my attention.)

Now, [I've been known to defend the cross-site duplication of content](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-should-be-sent-to-astronomy-stackexchange/726#726) in the past, but this feels distinctly different to me and offends sensibilities developed many years ago on the Usenet.

On the whole I feel we should discourage such intentional duplication, but I am interested to hear what other have to say.

---

Examples:

- [Remnant of a supernova](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/remnant-of-a-supernova) and [remnant of a supernova](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1194/211)
- [Rainbow around Sun](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14254/520) and [Rainbow around Sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1138/211)
- [the collision of Phobos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14212/520) and [The collision of Phobos](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1134/211)
- [two distant galaxies seen from earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13991/520) and [Galaxies seen from earth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1127/211) (despite the difference in titles the text is the same)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65931/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87739/ seem to apply

Comment: Good catch, David. As I read the high ranking answer to those instances right-at-the-same-time posting of identical questions is discouraged but successive posting of substantially similar questions that have been tailored as a result of earlier answer is OK. Is that how you read it?

Comment: Yep, that's my impression as well. I suppose someone might want to point out those discussions to the user in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross-posting questions across Stack Exchange sites is strongly discouraged. See

[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073)

> Allowing cross-posting [across the Stack Exchange network] is a slippery slope.
>
> If you might have slightly better odds of getting an answer by posting it on two sites, well, by gum, why not maximize your odds by posting it on *twenty sites!*
>
> There are some questions which fall into grey areas between sites, and I think it's OK to **ask and delete, then re-ask** if you feel you have asked on the wrong site.
>
> But as a general rule, do not cross-post questions, please. Pick a site and go with it.

It is also ok to ask *two different versions* of a question but you MUST tailor it to the audience on that site. Copying and pasting would put you on the road to account suspension.

(there's also the issue of cross-posting on multiple websites that aren't Stack Exchange sites.. so long as you're willing to be *responsible* for the question everywhere you asked it, this can be ok-ish.)