# Should I cross-post this question in chemistry.SE?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56800/stripeless-cleaning-of-windows) and given the number of upvotes and comments I think that there are quite some people interested. However, it seems from the comments and the lack of answers that the question might have a more chemical answer.

Would it be ok to cross-post it on chemistry.SE and report the answers (if any) on physics.SE as well? Or should I perhaps flag for migration?

The reason I am wondering about cross-posting is that, given the interest on physics.SE, it seems a bit illogical to migrate the questions, because the users at physics.SE can nog longer find the answer.

Comment: Did you read [the meta-link I offered](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/896/520) in the comments? It's been ten days without an answer. You're fine to try again on Chemistry now.

Comment: Yes I read the meta-link, but I was still unsure what a reasonable time-frame for cross-posting (in a different form) was

Answer (score 3):

I have [undeleted your post on chem](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/stripeless-cleaning-of-windows), for now. Stuff like this is exactly why I proposed [soft migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration).

It's a good fit for both sites, and cross posting isn't exactly forbidden, just discouraged. In [some](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150615/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice) [cases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice) it even leads to great results. In this case, since Physics.SE has been quite enthusiastic about the question, I'm reluctant to follow the "keep it on one site at a time" rule. [Jeff's objection](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/888/should-users-be-cross-posting-questions/896#896) to cross posting doesn't really apply here. And before you ask, you won't get suspended for having the same text in both posts -- it seems tailored equally well for both audiences.

We'll see if either version of the question gets answers. If one of them gets answers, then we can close the other and hat it with a "answers be here" link. Or leave it open; as long as they're linked to each other it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting. I will flag the posts appropriately if I get any answers.