# Is it OK to cross-post a question that you previously asked in other SE site?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

I was wondering if it was accepted. In my case, for instance, I asked a question in other SE site (astronomy) that would be also on topic here. Unfortunately it didn't get much attention since that site is smaller. I was wondering if I could ask it here too. I've read the FAQ and it doesn't seem to mention this, so I don't think this would be a problem, but I want to be sure.

If it is OK, should I delete the other question first or that is not necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cross-posting is [strongly discouraged](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/888/should-users-be-cross-posting-questions). That said, we are sometimes [lenient](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/should-i-cross-post-this-question-in-chemistry-se). Ultimately, what we really don't want is someone posting in multiple places but not disclosing this, an a scattershot attempt to get any sort of answer from anyone. This can potentially lead to wasted, duplicate effort in answering.

I would therefore say there are two cases where you can post the same question somewhere else:

1. You want a different take on the answer from a different community's perspective. Tailor the question appropriately, and note on both the old and new posts that there is a closely related question on another site. This doesn't really apply just if one community seems "better;" you really need to be looking for something "different."
2. You posted a question but either realized it belongs elsewhere or got no satisfactory response, and there is another site where it is on topic. This seems to be your case. In that case it's probably best to *migrate* the question rather than duplicate it. Use a custom moderator flag on the question and request it be migrated to the other site. The moderators can then do this (or not, if they so choose).

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting is not allowed on Stack-exchange. See this - [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

You could delete the Astronomy one and post on this site if you want.